# Project CRS Setting Invalid

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Somehow, my attempt at setting the QGIS project coordinate reference system to a Sinusoidal projection by defining the CRS' EPSG ID returns `Invalid CRS!`.

```
crs = 54008 # World Sinusoidal Projection

# Set project coordinate reference system (CRS)
spatRef = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

if spatRef.isValid():
    print("CRS Description: {}".format(spatRef.description()))
    print("CRS PROJ text: {}".format(spatRef.toProj4()))
    QgsProject.instance().setCrs(spatRef)
else:
    print("Invalid CRS!")
```

I use the long-term QGIS version 3.10.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look at the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) it appears that your `crs` code should be `EPSG:54008`.

However, looking at http://epsg.io/54008 - indicates that it is an `ESRI` code not `EPSG` so you may need to use

```
crs = "proj:+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```